# How to parse all selected checkboxes values with their quantities to Query String

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have:

```
while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    extract($row);
    echo "
    <input type='checkbox' name='additional[{$additional_id}]' value='{$additional_id}'/>{$additional_name} - &#36;{$additional_price} <input type='number' name='quantity_additional[{$additional_id}]' value='1' min='1' max='5'/><br/>
    ";
}
```

And I need to parse all the values of selected checkboxes with their quantities in this loop to this Query String:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.add').on('submit', function()
    {
        var product_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-id').text();
        var product_name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-name').text();
        var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
        //Here I need to serialize all values and quantities of the selected checkboxes then insert each of them in the Query String below
        window.location.href = "add_to_cart.php?product_id=" + product_id + "&product_name=" + product_name + "&quantity=" + quantity;
        return false;
    });
});
```

I think the Query String will need be something like:

```
add_to_cart.php?product_id=1&product_name=Pizza&quantity=2&additional_id=1&additional_quantity=2&additional_id=3&additional_quantity=5
```

The output query will be according to the number of selected additional checkboxes and their quantities. How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Check out the `Serialize()` function https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @jwatts1980 I've checked, but I do not know how to implement this function on my system.

Comment: I see. I would write out an answer, but I'm on my phone. It's very difficult to write code on a Swype keyboard lol.

Comment: @jwatts1980 No problem, I can wait. I will take this opportunity to ask you something else. I use this query string to later add this data into a SESSION. By this way can I use foreach to add each additional in the SESSION array?

Comment: Can't you just do `$("form").serialize()`?

Comment: Why can't you just submit the form normally with a get method? Why are you using javascript out of curiosity?

Comment: @Rasclatt Because I need to get the specified quantity for the product in that row.